# Load a DLL More Than Once?

Tags: c++, windows, linux, dll, shared-libraries

I'm using the [`LoadLibrary`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684175(v=vs.85).aspx) function to load a DLL in Windows. My question is this: If I call this method more than once for the same DLL, do I get handles to different instances of the DLL, or will they all refer to the same instance?

Additionally, how does this behaviour correlate to Linux SO files, is it the same or completely different, and what assumptions can I make in this regard? Thanks.

Comment: Do you want a separate instance of your DLL (and its global state)?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Possibly, but only if it can be done in Linux as well. I'm more trying to nail down how things 'usually' work. If what you describe is possible, I'd be interested in knowing how.

Comment: It works the same in operating systems. There is a dirty trick to get separate instances of the DLL. Each time you need a new instance, copy the file to a temporary location and give it a unique name. That way you force the system to load a new module. I've sometimes used this technique to work around libraries that are not threadsafe due to poor design and use of global state.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - Keep in mind that the *path* of the file is not the deciding factor, it's the *file name* that identifies it.

Comment: @polynomial not so. Loading two DLLs with the same name, but in different folders will result in two distinct modules being loaded. What you said was the case in 16 bit Windows I think.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - Sorry, turns out Google had sent me the the Windows CE documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms886736.aspx

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The MSDN documentation states:

> The system maintains a per-process reference count on all loaded
>   modules. Calling LoadLibrary increments the reference count. Calling
>   the FreeLibrary or FreeLibraryAndExitThread function decrements the
>   reference count. The system unloads a module when its reference count
>   reaches zero or when the process terminates (regardless of the
>   reference count).

So it would appear that loading the module more than once (without matching calls to FreeLibrary) will return the same handle.

Answer (score 3):

If the DLL is already loaded, `LoadLibrary` will simply return the address of the library in memory. However, `DllMain` is not called again with `DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH` when the second load is attempted. Handles in the sense of libraries are just memory locations, so the value you get the second time around should be the same as the first.

As far as linux SO files go, I don't see why they would load twice either. However, someone else will have to weigh in on this to give you a proper answer.

Answer (score 3):

For Linux shared objects, from the [`dlopen(3)` manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/3/dlopen):

> If the same library is loaded again with `dlopen()`, **the same file
>   handle is returned**. The `dl` library maintains reference counts for
>   library handles, so **a dynamic library is not deallocated until
>   `dlclose()` has been called on it as many times as `dlopen()` has
>   succeeded on it**. The **`_init()` routine, if present, is only called once**.
>   But a subsequent call with `RTLD_NOW` may force symbol resolution for a
>   library earlier loaded with `RTLD_LAZY`.

Comment: is this per process or for all processes?

Comment: @g19fanatic - for the same process.

Comment: For Linux you can use dlmopen()