# How to load a unmanaged dll into a seperate process for each request

Tags: asp.net, delphi, dll, unmanaged

In our ASP.NET application, we load a unmanaged dll (written in delphi) using the tag `DLLImport`. This DLL generates a PDF file using different parameters.

The problem is if two users try to generate a PDF at the same time, we get different errors since the progress can take some seconds.

Is there a way to load the DLL in a separate process for each user request? Or do we have to handle this in the DLL?

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "different users". Users of your app? Users of Windows? Opening the same app twice into two instances?

Comment: What errors did you get? We need more information. See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9190801/load-a-dll-more-than-once